# Replacing specific numbers in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

This code generate a matrix n m with alternate 3 and -3

```
n = 4;
m = 6;
M = zeros(m,n);
M(:,1) = 3*((-1).^(0:m-1).');
for ii = 2:n
    M(:,ii) = (-1)^(ii+1)*M(:,1)
end
```

Result for n=4 m=6

```
 3    -3     3    -3
-3     3    -3     3
 3    -3     3    -3
-3     3    -3     3
 3    -3     3    -3
-3     3    -3     3
```

Now, I am trying to replace the 3 with a 0 and the -3 with a 1 in this way:

```
M(M==3)  = 0
M(M==-3) = 1
```

But I do not get what I need because the result is the following:

```
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     1    -1
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     1    -1
 0     1     0     0
 1     0     1    -1
```

How can I achieve the replacement of 3 with 0 and -3 with 1?

Comment: You forgot an `end` in your question's code, I added it

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. See my execution log below. Can you clarify your issue or update with code that reproduces the issue?
http://pastebin.com/Cj3EqFHC

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
M = (sign(M) + 1)/2
```

another one:

```
M = ~(M - 3)
```

but your idea is working perfectly for me also, are you sure that you copied it correctly?

```
M(M== 3) = 0
M(M==-3) = 1
```

There is no reason, why it shouldn't work. Apart from how you generating it. So maybe there are floating point issues occurring. So to be sure, do at first:

```
M = round(M)
```

---

An alternative way to generate your matrix, without a loop could be:

```
M = 3*   bsxfun(@(x,y) 2*(~mod(x+y,2)-1/2),(1:m)',1:n)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The output I copied is exactly what I get. However if I generate the matrix as per your suggestion, than the final output is correct. So the problem is in the matrix generation. I do not get why but is there.

Comment: @FeliceM and have you tried `M = round(M);M(M== 3) = 0;
M(M==-3) = 1`? That should work too!

Comment: I did it but does not work.  I am very interested in understanding why the classic replacement M(M==3)= 0 did not work in such matrix. I just started playing with Matlab for my own culture. It did work with your alternative way to do the matrix.

Comment: Cannot reproduce OP's issue, please review my comment in the question. While this answer provides alternative approaches, I don't think this answer truly addresses the OP's real issue.